# Update the APNs certificate and change the Apple ID

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Our APNs certificate is about to expire as it shows on FireBase console. I need to renew it. I have 2 main issues:

1. I visited Apple's website:

```
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/download/{some code}
```

where `{some code}` is some kind of a an id, presumably.
I do not see a "renew" just "revoke" and "download":
[image]
Checked with the original Apple ID that created the certificate as well as another one.

2. The guy who originally created the certificate is leaving, so I need to have the option to renew it with a different Apple ID in the future.

As I understand, if I revoke the certificate and create a new one, that would stop the push notifications and all devices would have to "enroll again". What does that mean exactly? Would that mean sending a new update? What would have to change on the client/server side?

Comment: Where did you read about the "enroll again"? As far as I know you just need to create a new certificate, and there is no need to revoke the older one.

Comment: @ArikSegal all tutorials I found mentioned that. Here's a specific one https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2960965

Comment: You must renew the certificate with the same Apple ID credentials used to get the original certificate. It is also important to renew the same certificate that was originally uploaded in the console. If you use different credentials or renew an different certificate, you are not renewing the certificate but rather generating a new certificate. When you apply this new certificate to the Workspace ONE UEM Console, the communication breaks between the Workspace ONE UEM Console and the iOS devices associated with the original certificate. If this happens, you must then re-enroll every iOS device..

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a new certificate and updated the one in FireBase and it worked. Didn't have to revoke the previous one. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5Tb1iD6FgI&t=193s).